# How to disable an item clicked in a gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview

**Hello everyone!**

I was trying to disable an item after clicking on a gridview did not work.

I have seen that you have to override the methods:

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled () {
     return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled (int position) {
     return false;
}
```

and implement, but the gridview is dynamic so I can not do fixed position.

**In any case, I could say as disable (with the methods above) the item I am currently clicking?.**

Also tried the method OnItemClickListener disable the current view but it did not work.

**What I need is that the gridview (which has only letters) can touch each letter once, only once.**

Hope you can help!

**Greetings to all and sorry for my English!**